# iOS Swipe to delete with an upside down UITableVIew

Tags: ios8, cgaffinetransform, uiswipegesturerecognizer

My app needs to have a table view that works like Apple's Messages app. When you add a cell to it the cell appears at the bottom of the screen, when you you another, it scrolls up and the new cell is now at the bottom of the screen.

This is pretty easy to do with an CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

```
_tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
```

I also need to transform the cell so its now upside contents are displayed upside down, and therefore really rightside up.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (MyCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    return cell;    
}
```

This works fine in iOS7 and iOS8 except my swipe to delete gesture in iOS8 is, well, also upside down! The swipe to delete gesture now has to come in from the left and side and swipe to the right. (And yes, it took awhile to discover this!)

I know how to write

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And that works fine (except of course my custom buttons are upside down, but another transform will fix that) but I have no idea how to get the swipe to come from the other side.

Comment: Not sure about how to implement everything so I'm adding this as a comment, but one thing I should point out: that isn't an "upside-down" tableView in the Messages app, it's a tableView that is auto-scrolled to the last row.  You can insert rows at the bottom with `insertRowAtIndexPath` and have the indexPath be the last one in the table.  No need to rotate anything.

Comment: I tried that, using the "giant blank header" to ensure that when you had only a few items the blank space was at the top, not the bottom. But that had problems of its own, that I can't remember now. It could just have been an error in how I calculated the blank header size.